# Why does "A=10 echo $A" not print 10?

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

This command:

```
A=10 echo $A
```

prints an empty line. Why not `10`? Why doesn't the in-place temporary environment setting work?

I want to know the reason and explanation rather than solution.

I used

```
LANG=C gcc ...
```

to force gcc use the fallback language (English) instead of the system language (Chinese). So I assume a `VAR=value` prefix will setup a temporary environment for the command following it. But it looks like I have some misunderstanding.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's a matter of the order in which the different steps of evaluating a command happen.

`A=10 echo $A` first parses the command into a simple command made of three words `A=10`, `echo` and `$A`. Then each word undergoes variable substitution, i.e. the transformation of variable expansions such as `$A` into their values (I'm omitting steps that do nothing visible).

If `A` has the value `foo` initially, the result of the expansion steps is a simple command which still has three words: `A=10`, `echo` and `foo`. (The shell also remembers at this point which characters were initially within quotes — in this case, none.) The next step is to execute the command. Since `A=10` begins with a valid variable name followed by an equal sign, it is treated as an assignment; the variable `A` is set to `10` in both the shell and the environment during the execution of the command. (Normally you need to write `export A` to have `A` in the environment and not just as a shell variable; this is an exception.) The next word is not an assignment, so it's treated as a command name (it's a built-in command). The `echo` command does not depend on any variable, so `A=10 echo $A` has exactly the same effect as `echo $A`.

If you want to set a variable for the duration of a command only, but taking the assignment into account while executing the command, you can use a subshell. A subshell, indicated by parentheses, makes all state changes (variable assignments, current directory, function definitions, etc.) local to the subshell.

```
(A=10; echo $A)
```

Make that `export A=10` if you want to export the variable to the environment so that it is seen by external programs.

Comment: Thanks, can I say `A=10 (echo $A)` and get `10`?

Comment: @EarthEngine No, that would be a syntax error. The assignment has to be at the start of a simple command (i.e. just a command name and some parameters, and optionally some initial assignments and some redirections). `A=10; (echo $A)` outputs `10` but also sets `A` for the remainder of the script.

Comment: @EarthEngine But you can say `A=10 eval 'echo $A'`. The single-quotes stop `$A` being interpreted until the whole line is evaluated... By which time A=10. I consider this answer *more right* than the accepted.

Comment: I think this is the correct explanation. The reason for the behavior is just the order of when the expansion of `$A` and the assignment of `A` is happening. E.g. `A=5; A=6 let 'a=A'; echo $a` returns `6` not `5` and I don't think `let` starts a subshell, since it's a builtin command.

Comment: @EarthEngine: When it's said that the correct explanation is the *order* of evaluation, it may be misleading: `A=10 echo $A` will *not* set `A=10` for any commands afterwards, even if they are in different lines (when clearly the assignment *was* already evaluated). It's not about order, it's about *scope*

Comment: @MestreLion There is an assignment of `A` in the current shell, but it only lasts for the current simple command. You can only observe the difference in very narrow circumstances: only if the command is a regular builtin and it makes use of a variable's value (such as `IFS=… read`).

Comment: @MestreLion: To quote the bash info page here: **"If no command name results, the variable assignments affect the current shell environment.  Otherwise, the variables are added to the  environment of the executed command and do not affect the current shell environment."**

So the assignment is done by the shell. The only difference between an assignment with a command and without a command is in which environment this assignment gets defined. The shell has to create the initial environment of the called command anyway.

Comment: @Gilles: got it, thanks! I'll delete my comments that make such claim.

Answer (score 38):

When you use `LANG=C gcc ...`  what happens is that the shell sets LANG for `gcc`'s environment *only*, and *not* for the *current* environment itself (*see note*). So after `gcc`finishes, `LANG` is back to its previous value (or unset).

Additionally, when you use `A=10 echo $A` it is the *shell* that replaces $A, not echo, and this substitution (called "expansion") happens *before* the statement is evaluated (including the assignment), so to work as expected `A`'s value must be already set in the *current* environment prior to that statement.

That's why `A=10 echo $A` does not work as expected: `A=10` will be set for echo, but echo internally ignores the value of the environment variable `A`. And `$A` is replaced with the value set in the *current shell* (which is none), and *then* passed as an argument to echo.

So your assumption is correct: `VAR=value command` *does* work, but this is only relevant if `command` internally *uses* VAR. If not, you can still pass `value` as an *argument* to `command`, but arguments are replaced by the *current* shell, so they must be set prior to usage: `VAR=value; command "$VAR"`

If you know how to create an executable script, you can try this as a test:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "1st argument is $1"
echo "A is $A"
```

Save it as `testscript` and try:

```
$ A=5; A=10 testscript "$A"; echo "$A"
1st argument is 5
A is 10
5
```

Last but not least, it's worth knowing the difference between *shell* and *environment* variables and program *arguments*.

Here are some good references:

- [How To Read and Set Environmental and Shell Variables on a Linux VPS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-read-and-set-environmental-and-shell-variables-on-a-linux-vps)
- [Understanding Unix shells and environment variables](http://www.kingcomputerservices.com/unix_101/understanding_unix_shells_and_environment_variables.htm)

.

(*) Note: technically the shell *does* set in current environment too, and here's why: Some commands, like `echo`, `read` and `test` are *shell builtins*, and as such they don't spawn a child process. They run in current environment. But the shell takes care for the assignment only lasts until the command is running, so for all practical purposes the effect is the same: the assignment is only seen by that single command.

Comment: This explanation is actually incorrect, although it results in the correct conclusion in all but a few corner cases. The real explanation is the order of expansion: `$A` is evaluated before the assignment takes place. I think your explanation only fails in the case of regular built-in utilities whose behavior depends on the value of the variable: the built-in does see the assigned value. A common example is `IFS=: read one two three rest`, which reads colon-separated fields: the `read` builtin does see the value of `IFS`.

Comment: “not for the current shell itself” is wrong: the variable is set in the current shell, but it only lasts for the current simple command. `echo` would see the value `10` for `A`, if it cared.

Comment: @Gilles: thanks a lot for the clarification! I wasn't aware of this subtlety. So, if I understood correctly, bash *has* to set for the *current* environment otherwise builtins (which don't spawn a new `pid`) would not see the assignment as other "regurlar" commands would. But it *unsets* after the command is done to limit the assignment scope. Is this is correct, I'll fix my answer accordingly.
PS: technicalities aside, I still think an answer should emphasize on the scope aspect, not evaluation order, otherwise one could think `A=10 test; echo $A` will print 10

Answer (score 3):

One possibly clean way to do what you apparently desire is to issue the command:

```
A=10 eval 'echo $A'
```

Which will in effect defer the substitution of the value 10 into the place of $A to a later context (ie, 'inside' the eval, which already knows about the assignment). Note that the single quotes are essential. Such a construct cleanly communicates the assignment to your desired command (echo in this case) without running the risk of polluting your current environment.